# How do I add source code generated by a tool to my Netbeans Ant project?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, antlr4, code-generation

I'm using ANTLR4 to generate a parser and lexer for a project with Netbeans and Ant.  I was able to add a "-pre-compile" target override to my build.xml that executes the ANTLR4 tool to generate Java files for the lexer and parser.

But how do I add those automatically generated .java files to my project so that my user code which depends on the generated code will compile?